# I'm a clean coder

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

Definitions:

> Clean code - is readable and easy to understand by everyone whether the reader is the author of the code or a new programmer
>
> Coder - a person who writes code for computer programs.

So If I use these defintions this way, is that correct?

> I'm a clean coder.

This is the full text where I have put on Upwork profile:

> I always follow the best coding pattern and practices. I'm a clean coder.

Do you know a better way to tell this?

Comment: I don't think that's for you to say.  What do others say?

Comment: @HotLicks I need to tell this to my Clients. i.e. on Upwork platform

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clean_coder

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is nice :) @Weoathtocreation

Comment: I write clean code.

Comment: See Robert C. Martin's book _The Clean Coder_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to say this would be simply "I write clean code," or "I code cleanly". If you say you're a "clean coder", you *might* be understood as one who writes understandable code, but it could also easily be interpreted to mean that you're a coder who recently took a shower (i.e. not dirty). I'd avoid saying "clean coder" without more context, as it's very unclear whether you intend to mean that the code is clean, or the coder themself is clean.

Comment: I put this `I always follow the best coding pattern and practices. I'm a clean coder.` Any good way, please?

Comment: @Sampath It's definitely better with context, but still sounds a bit strange to my ear. Perhaps change the second sentence to "My code is clean."

Comment: "I write clean code" is fine, but "I code cleanly" sounds a bit odd. As someone who knows the term *clean code*, the idea of a person who is *a clean coder* is not especially ambiguous. I think the risk of ambiguity is less than the risk of sounding odd saying "I code cleanly".